# How to create a search page and function in basic web app

Tags: model-view-controller, search, controller

I have a fairly simple MVC webapp connected to a database. The user needs a search page that will pull certain records from a single table. The user can give 1 or more keywords. The search function must search for records containing those keywords in 3 different columns: title, description or poc.

I've got the following setup but its incorrect. It is providing records containing any of the keywords. The results must instead be records containing all keywords. Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way of writing a search function...

```
// searchString contains all keywords delimited by spaces
string[] keywordArray = Regex.Split(searchString, "\\s");

var model = new List<MyTable>();
foreach (string word in keywordArray)
{
   foreach (var record in myTableRepository.MyTable.Where(x => x.title.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()) || (x.description != null && x.description.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower())) || (x.poc != null && x.poc.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))).ToList())
   {
       model.Add(new MyTable
       {
          id = record.id,
          title = record.title,
          description = record.description, 
          poc = record.poc
       });
   }
}
return View(model);
```

For example, if the user gave the following search criteria "john test phase", then the results could look like this:

```
title                   description                  poc
Lorem Ipsum Test A      Phase A lorem ipsum          john doe
Lorem Ipsum phase       This is john test for jack   jane doe
Lorem Ipsum             John test for jim            clark phase
```

etc..

Thanks in advance for advice and tips!

Comment: "MVC" is a **language independent** design pattern, not a name for a framework or application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to search one record at a time and check for all the keywords within one record. Perhaps you could collect all the words associated with a particular entry in one variable and then search that for all the keywords.

```
// searchString contains all keywords delimited by spaces
string[] keywordArray = Regex.Split(searchString, "\\s");

var model = new List<MyTable>();
Boolean searchResult;
foreach (var record in myTableRepository.MyTable)
{
    searchResult = true;

    var recordTerms = record.title + " " + record.description + " " + record.poc;
    recordTerms = recordTerms.toLower();
    recordArray = Regex.Split(recordTerms, "\\s");

    foreach (var word in keywordArray)
    {
        if (!recordArray.asList.contains(word))
            searchResult = false;
        }
    }

    if (searchResult) {
        model.Add(new MyTable
        {
            id = record.id,
            title = record.title,
            description = record.description, 
            poc = record.poc
        });
    }
}
return View(model);
```

Comment: That is a better solution. Thanks!